xlsx::write.xlsx() crashes on tibble with 2+ rows and row.names = F parameter
When I call xlsx::write.xlsx() on a tibble with 2+ rows it crashes:
df <- structure(list(`region name` = c("Reg 1", "Reg 2"), 
                     `value` = c(1.38755717255717, 1.26297588082289)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

xlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F)

and returns:
Error in if (is.na(value)) { : the condition has length > 1

1st option
If I call the same script setting default row.names = T it executes properly but adds an unneeded column with row number.
xlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "myfilename.xlsx", 
    row.names = T) # I can skip the parameter
    


2nd option
If I subset only one row from the tibble the script executes entirely as expected.
xlsx::write.xlsx(df[1, ], file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F)


3rd option
If I convert data to data frame it executes without an error but modifies column names due to data.frame restrictions:
xlsx::write.xlsx(data.frame(df), file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F)


Is it a bug in xlsx::write.xlsx() or I can do something with it?

Thank you all owner of the repository at Github @cole labeled the issue as a bug.

That happens because you are coercing to data.frame your df object which is ALREADY a data.frame by applying data.frame(df). When you do that, the data.frame function performs an automatic (unwanted in your case) name correction process.
Solution 1: Put df directly as the first argument.
Solution 2: If you still need to coerce your object to data.frame before entering it into write.xlsx, apply the argument check.names = FALSE as follows:
xlsx::write.xlsx(data.frame(df, check.names = FALSE), 
                 file = "myfilename.xlsx", 
                 row.names = FALSE)


Thank you for your solutions. Please kindly refer to the first part of my question. At the beginning I put df as the first argument of the function. The script returned the error posted in my question. I was wondering why xlsx::write.xlsx() did not accept the data structure that was already a data.frame without all the above mentioned options (explicit cast, single row subsetting, forced row name outputting)

In other words why xlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F) crashes and  1. xlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = T), 2. xlsx::write.xlsx(df[1, ], file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F), 3. xlsx::write.xlsx(data.frame(df, check.names = FALSE), file = "myfilename.xlsx", row.names = F) don't?
